# Strategy Index on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I'm using MongoDB version 5, and I have a collection that contains around 2 million documents.

In my web application I have the possibility to filter this collection by eight fields, and each field is optional. None are required.

What is the best strategy to increase search performance?

Each combination of filters has an equal chance of being used.

Comment: This sounds a little like a conversation piece rather than a question but nonetheless, it won't surprise you to hear that it all depends on the data and will require some test and adjust while you create/drop/create indexes. Creating a compound index that supports specific queries is one of the recognised strategies you can adopt. How is the data distributed in terms of size? By that I mean are any of the fields data heavy (large arrays etc) and are any of the fields boolean/int?

Comment: I won't pretend my strategy is the best, but I opted to reactive approach in most cases - monitor slow logs, identify room for performance improvement based on stats (the slowest / most frequent queries), check if an index can improve it (data distribution / cardinality etc).  I'd close the question as opinion based if there was no bounty.

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75176637/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Answer (score 0):

Before drilling into a pure MongoDB solution, I suggest that you'll to consider a [**MongoDB - Elasticsearch** integration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/enterprise-search/current/mongodb-start.html). This is a common pattern and it will eliminate any search performance issues :)

If additional search capabilities will be required in the future, for sure this will be a beneficial path and payoff maintaining additional components.

You will be able to play around with MongoDB indexes and maybe suit it to your specific requirements, but it will underperform comparing to dedicated search engine.

Now for a pure MongoDB solution (and mostly understanding its limitations.. )

Assuming base line of "n" single column indexes:

```js
// Keep {sparse: true} for non-text, since you index optional fields
// Index single field
db.test1.createIndex( { field1: 1 }, { sparse: true } )
db.test1.createIndex( { field2: 1 }, { sparse: true } )
...
db.test1.createIndex( { fieldN: 1 }, { sparse: true } )

// adding also one multiple fields index
db.test1.createIndex( { field1: 1 , field2: 1  }, { sparse: true } )
```

If you'll check what happens when you execute a query (using `explain()`) you'll notice that MongoDB will search by the best index it can find, and then filter the results.

For example, searching by three fields:

`db.test1.find({field1: "a2", field2: "xx", field3: "yy" }).explain().queryPlanner.winningPlan`, results in:

```json
  winningPlan: {
    stage: 'FETCH',
    filter: {
      '$and': [ { field2: { '$eq': 'xx' } }, { field3: { '$eq': 'yy' } } ]
    },
    inputStage: {
      stage: 'IXSCAN',
      keyPattern: { field1: 1 },
      indexName: 'field1_1',
      ....
}
```

Here we see that it searched by index of field1, and filtered the remaining results. Note that it could have chosen to use the complex index for fields `field1`+`field2`, but it didn't—so for the general case it is not necessarily a benefit to add multi-field indexes.

Had we created a field1+field2+field3 index, we would get a better performance on the above query, but it is certainly not a smart thing to exhaust indexing on all possible permutations.

You may achieve some partial leverage by indexing "most used" user search patterns, or based on data density on optional fields. also consider [partial indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-partial/) in case of applicative relation between fields.

But again from my experience, I'd recommend a proper search engine.

Answer (score -1):

Based on business needs or logs, it is learned that the most commonly used field queries will add indexes to frequently queried fields. For example, if you establish a joint index of 5 fields, any query of 5 fields will follow this index

Comment: "if you establish a joint index of 5 fields, any query of 5 fields will follow this index" is a very wrong statement. It's not how compound indices work in mongo.

Comment: @AlexBlex I have different opinions， What can be included in my understanding 
 https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#create-compound-indexes-to-support-several-different-queries

Comment: This one https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/core/indexes/index-types/index-compound/#index-prefixes

Answer (score -2):

Given the nature of your query where each field is optional and can be used in any combination, creating a compound index for each possible combination would be impractical and expensive in terms of memory and write performance.
Instead, you can consider using the Attribute Pattern as mentioned in the related answer

1. This pattern involves creating an extra attribute in each document that holds key-value pairs for each field. You can then create a compound index on this attribute.

Here is an example of how your document could look:

```
json
{
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",
    "field3": "value3",
    //...
    "search": [
        {"k": "field1",  "v": "value1"},
        {"k": "field2",  "v": "value2"},
        {"k": "field3",  "v": "value3"},
        //...
    ]
}
```

You would then create a compound index on search.k and search.v.
When querying, you would need to adapt your queries to match this structure. For example, a query for documents where field1 is value1 and field2 is value2 would look like this:

```
json
{
    "$and":[
        {"search":{"$elemMatch": {"k": "field1", "v": "value1"}}},
        {"search":{"$elemMatch": {"k": "field2", "v": "value2"}}}
    ]
}
```

This approach should provide fast query results even with a large number of documents and a large number of possible filter combinations.

Remember, indexing comes with a cost of increased memory usage and potential impact on write performance. Therefore, monitor your system's performance and adjust your indexing strategy as necessary.

Comment: That is an interesting approach, haven't seen that before.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I guess you didn't see it because it doesn't work =) not in v6 anyway, and as much as I understand indices it won't work with b-tree in general. Mongo will use index only for a single $elemMatch. The planner will likely test all, but will pick only one. In this regard it won't be different from regular indices one per field. With regular indices there is a slim chance than in theory it might trigger index intersection scenario. Altho I haven't seen it either =)

Comment: @AlexBlex: ah, that could explain it :)

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT